# using wget against protected site with NTLM

Tags: wget, ntlm, mirroring

Trying to mirror a local intranet site and have found previous questions using 'wget'.  It works great with sites that are anonymous, but I have not been able to use it against a site that is expecting username\password (IIS with Integrated Windows Authentication).

Here is what I pass in:

> wget -c --http-user='domain\user' --http-password=pwd http://local/site -dv

Here is the debug output (note I replaced some with dummy values obviously):

```
Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.11.4 on Windows-MSVC.

--2009-07-14 09:39:04--  http://local/site
Host `local' has not issued a general basic challenge.
Resolving local... seconds 0.00, x.x.x.x
Caching local => x.x.x.x
Connecting to local|x.x.x.x|:80... seconds 0.00, connected.
Created socket 1896.
Releasing 0x003e32b0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /site/ HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.11.4
Accept: */*
Host: local
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2009 13:39:04 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Content-Length: 4431
Content-Type: text/html

---response end---
401 Access Denied
Closed fd 1896
Unknown authentication scheme.
Authorization failed.
```

Answer (score 10):

NTLM authentication is broken in wget 1.11, use 1.10 instead.

Comment: Adding a link to the relevant bug ticket would be useful here

Comment: Not able to test yet if it is true. But i confirm different behavior in stdout in NTLM case.
http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-wget@gnu.org/msg00003.html

Comment: I also cannot confirm that works for me as well. `wget --version` reports `GNU Wget 1.12 built on cygwin. +digest +ipv6 +nls +ntlm +opie +md5/openssl +https -gnutls +openssl +iri`. But in my case server offers `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` only (which I believe is either `NTLM` or `Kerberos` – to be negotiated).

Comment: One of my friends bumps into this today and alerts me today. I tried it on eight-year old SuSE 10.1, wget 1.10.2, works great. Wget 1.11 fails with inexplicably HTTP 401 error after retrieving the first page. Web server is an Apache+SVN+mod_auth_sspi-1.0.4-2.2.2 .

Comment: Some hours later, my friend cleverly use ``--auth-no-challenge`` to work around this problem(wget offers to use ``Authorization: Basic`` and server accepts it). And I confirmed that wget 1.10.2 on SuSE 10.1 also take the ``Authorization: Basic`` measure.

Comment: After some more investigation, I have to correct myself here. My previous two comments did not clarify whether wget deals with NTLM correctly. Actually, wget's NTLM behavior seems to be in mist, which I cannot explain until I fully understand NTLM protocol.

Answer (score 10):

Curl is actually probably a better tool for fetching content from NTLM-authenticated web servers.  You can get an equivalent function to your proposed wget command line by using:

```
curl --anyauth --user username:password http://someserver/site
```

Comment: Using "--ntlm" instead of "--anyauth" worked for me. Otherwise, I think it chose "negotiate" authentication which failed ("--ntlm --negotiate" also failed).

Comment: `curl --anyauth --user 'username:password' http://someserver/site` worked for me with the `usernname:password` wrapped with single quotatio marks.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen references to being able to use the [NTLM Authorization Proxy Server](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) to get around these types of problems.

Answer (score 1):

use `--auth-no-challenge` option (wget 1.11+) (it's now considered unsafe)

Comment: Why is it now considered unsafe? Unsafe in what way?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
It is work-around for Basic auth IIS7.

When auth is successeful it send next http header:

```
'Authorization: < type > < credentials >'.
```

So we able to do authorization in browser and 
copy this header params from browser (firebug addon) or generate:

```
$ echo -en 'username:password' | base64
dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK
$ echo 'dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK' | base64 -d
username:password
```

example:

```
$ wget --header="Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK" http://example.com/
```